# Included file outside of div, even though inside tags in the HTML code

Tags: html, django-templates

I have such a weird problem. The following template code is from my base.html in a Django project. The key part to look at is how the mobile/footer.html is inside the div "mobile-wrapper". And yet on just one of the pages (password change) it shows up outside of it! Here is a firebug screenshot of that page that, like every other page, extends "mobile/base.html" and yet the "footer-wrapper" (the only thing in the mobile/footer.html-file, see below) shows up outside of "mobile-wrapper". Basically, I have no idea how this is possible.

[image: Firebug screenshot]

mobile/base.html

```
<body>
    <div class="mobile-wrapper">
            {% include 'mobile/navbar.html' %}

            <div id="fb-app-id" rel="{{ FB_APP_ID }}"></div>
            <div id="site-address" rel='http://{{ SITE_ROOT }}'></div>
            <div id="image-address" rel='http://{{ SITE_ROOT }}/static/global/images/lbog_logo_large.png'></div>

            {% include 'fbscript.html' %}

            <div id="my-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid" id="body-wrapper">               
                    <div id="fb-root"></div>

                    {% block content %}

                    {% endblock content %}

                </div>
            </div>

            {% include 'mobile/footer.html' %}
    </div>

<script src="{% static "global/js/form_listeners.js" %}"></script>

{% block extrascripts %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
```

mobile/footer.html

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="container footer" id="my-footer">
        <a href="#">Back to Top</a> <b>|</b> 
        <a href="{% url 'feedback' %}">Feedback / Tell us Your Story</a> <b>|</b> 
        <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a> <b>|</b> 
        <a href="{% url 't-and-c' %}">Terms and Conditions</a><br>
        <div class="span3" id="fb-buttons">
{#                 <a href="{% url 'fbtest' %}">Fb test</a> #}
                <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" onlogin="OnRequestPermission();">
                </fb:login-button>
                <button class="my-fb-like" onclick="postLike('http://{{ SITE_ROOT }}{% url 'home' %}')"></button>
                <button class="my-fb-share" onclick="postShare('http://{{ SITE_ROOT }}{% url 'home' %}')"></button>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is there css rules applied in "footer-wrapper"?

try this css and see if it works...

```
 div:after 
 {
     content:".";
     clear:both;
     visibility:hidden;
     display:block;
     height:0px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. There are no styles applied to footer-wrapper. The "container footer" styles are for bootstrap, but I'm not sure it would explain why the footer suddenly appears outside the mobile-wrapper.